# UML one-to-one diagram

Tags: uml

I would like to ask you which of these UML diagram is best according to "best practices".
One is given by my teacher and the other is mine, but the main difference I have doubts is the one-to-one vs. attribute with no one-to-one relationship. Please, could you tell me why should be one better than the other?

[image]

[image]

The problem also said: "The ConsejoDepartamento has to have one director that is a Miembro, but must be a Profesor. So does the secretario too"

(Please, excuse my bad English!)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your class diagram should describe a conceptual level of your system, the second choice is definitively the best: show relationships between classes. Having typed attributes in classes is more related to the implementation, and it shows how you're going to implement it. 
To summary your question sounds like: "Should I model the code I'll write or should I design the system no matter how It will be coded?" . Software architects would choose option 2. 
HTH